# '@' as a Character inside razor string not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the code below which is basically some embed script code inside an MVC view, everything builds fine but when I run I get this error "The name 'B6' does not exist in the current context", I assume this has to do with the '@' character as this is used with razor to reference variables, I've searched for some way to escape the '@' but have had no luck.

@url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebFormServeServlet?rid=fwW-@B6-MHnNRgi";

Comment: Strange. I did a google search on `razor escape @` and found lots of examples, the first one leading to a question here. Which search terms did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your code

```
@{string url="https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebFormServeServlet?rid=fwW-@@B6-MHnNRgi";}

<script src='@url'></script>
```

Comment: Ok, I have added this to my code after the above declaration <script src='@Url'></script> i get the following printed out when I run the page  System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebFormServeServlet?rid=fwW-@B6-MHnNRgi"

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: @Url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebFormServeServlet?rid=fwW-@@B6-MHnNRgi"  
         <script src='@Url'></script>

Comment: No still not working -- Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Comment: @user3165925 i have mistakenly type `;` plz check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1) Use `@@`, which will escape the `@` sign.

```
@url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebFormServeServlet?rid=fwW-@@B6-MHnNRgi"
```

2) Use a verbatim string: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx

`@url = @"https://crm.zoho.com/crm/WebFormServeServlet?rid=fwW-@B6-MHnNRgi"`